# Implement general number of arguments in lispy.py

Tags: python, scheme, interpreter

I'm learning how to implement an Scheme interpreter in python. I was looking at [lispy.py](https://www.csee.umbc.edu/courses/331/fall13/03/code/python/scheme/lispy.py) and I was wondering how I could change the code so that the arithmetic operations work on a general amount of numbers like so.

```
lispy> (+ 1 2 3 4)
10
lispy> (* 1 2 3)
6
lispy> (+ 4 5 6)
15
```

In its current state, lispy.py can only handle two numbers at a time, i.e.

```
lispy> (+ 1 2)
3
lispy> (+ 3 4)
7
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done the lispy way:

```
(+ (+ (+ 1 2) 3) 4)
```

or if you want it the way you have described you can add and modify the lispy.py as follows:

```
.
.
.
def special_add(*numbers):
    sum = 0
    for number in numbers:
        sum += number
    return sum

def add_globals(self):
    "Add some Scheme standard procedures."
    import math, cmath, operator as op
    self.update(vars(math))
    self.update(vars(cmath))
    self.update({
     '+':special_add, '-':op.sub, '*':op.mul, '/':op.div, 'not':op.not_, 
     '>':op.gt, '<':op.lt, '>=':op.ge, '<=':op.le, '=':op.eq, 
     'equal?':op.eq, 'eq?':op.is_, 'length':len, 'cons':cons,
     'car':lambda x:x[0], 'cdr':lambda x:x[1:], 'append':op.add,  
     'list':lambda *x:list(x), 'list?': lambda x:isa(x,list),
     'null?':lambda x:x==[], 'symbol?':lambda x: isa(x, Symbol),
     'boolean?':lambda x: isa(x, bool), 'pair?':is_pair, 
     'port?': lambda x:isa(x,file), 'apply':lambda proc,l: proc(*l), 
     'eval':lambda x: eval(expand(x)), 'load':lambda fn: load(fn), 'call/cc':callcc,
     'open-input-file':open,'close-input-port':lambda p: p.file.close(), 
     'open-output-file':lambda f:open(f,'w'), 'close-output-port':lambda p: p.close(),
     'eof-object?':lambda x:x is eof_object, 'read-char':readchar,
     'read':read, 'write':lambda x,port=sys.stdout:port.write(to_string(x)),
     'display':lambda x,port=sys.stdout:port.write(x if isa(x,str) else to_string(x))})
    return self
.
.
.
```

where you can see that I have added the function `special_add` and replaced what function is used for the `'+'` operator to this newly defined function.

*) Edited the code to handle also the empty and one input cases.

Comment: Note, that this implementation handles addition. If you want the same behavior for multiplication, you can follow the same pattern.

Comment: Another comment: It is possible to replace the special_add function with a lambda expression, using reduce as `'+':lambda *nbrs: reduce(op.add, nbrs, 0)`